# Passing id in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor Pages and ASP.NET in general.
So I have a **class** called **UserInfo**. All view models have access to this class.
On my login page, if login is successful it will pass the `UserId` and takes me back to the main page. Also updates all information in the **UserInfo**.
When I try to access that class in view to say hi to the user I can't get any other information than the id that was passed in the url. I cant even run SQL codes to figure it out that way.
How do I only pass id and find everything else using that id? Is it possible to have that id saved somewhere (in a class or something) so I don't have to pass anything?

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    sqlcon.Open();
    sqlcom = new SqlCommand("select* from users where userusername='" + Userinfo.Username + "'", sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    if (reader[2].ToString() == Userpassword)
    {
        Userinfo.UserID = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
        Userinfo.Userusername = reader[1].ToString();
        Userinfo.Username = reader[3].ToString();
        return RedirectToPage("/index", new { UserId = Userinfo.UserID });
    }
    else
    {               
        return RedirectToPage("/Login");
    }
}
```

Here is where it says welcome to the user. It only says welcome because somehow **userinfo.username** is still empty even though I assigned a name to it in the login page?! `UserId` is a variable that i passed to the url that's the only thong that's not empty/null!

```
@{
    if (Model.UserId != null)
    {
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome  @Model.UserName</h1>
    }
    else
    {
        <h1 class="display-4">Good to see you!</h1>
        <label class="text-secondary">Please login to access your dashboard</label>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your application is redirecting to /Index page (GET) and Userinfo no longer has the values it had in the previous request (OnPost).

```
return RedirectToPage("/index", new { UserId = Userinfo.UserID });
```

I can't see where Userinfo is instantiated in your example (Controller constructor maybe?) but please remember HTTP is stateless.

One way to acheive what you're looking for is using TempData. TempData will persist for only one request. Before redirecting to /index...

```
TempData["UserInfo"] = Userinfo;
return RedirectToPage("/index", new { UserId = Userinfo.UserID });
```

Within the /index action...

```
var userInfo = TempData["UserInfo"] as UserInfo;
if (userInfo != null) {

   return View(userInfo);
}
```

On your cshtml page, I'm assuming you've already declared something like...

```
@model UserInfo
```

Another way would to do a lookup on the user again within the /index action using the UserId query parameter. This way you wouldn't need TempData.

As a side note, please consider parameterising your SQL to prevent SQL injection.

```
sqlcom = new SqlCommand("select* from users where userusername='" + Userinfo.Username + "'", sqlcon);
```

Also, make sure you dispose/close your open SQL Connection to prevent leaks (e.g. if your select statement throws an SqlException for what ever reason, you want to make sure connection is cleaned up afterwards) via using statement or in a finally block